# Creating and joining Python data frames

Tags: python, mysql, python-2.7

I am creating two dataframes from MySQL database query results, later I join them on a column and get the final result.

Below is the code I currently have

```
import MySQLdb
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost",    # your host, usually localhost
                     user="root",         # your username
                     passwd="M@nUtd10",  # your password
                     db="Mediator")        # name of the data base

cur = db.cursor()

from pandas import DataFrame

cur.execute("SELECT invoice_ref_2 AS PPS_Id ,cast(total_amount  AS char(10)) AS Amount FROM core_invoices  WHERE  client_ref_id like 'payment_gc_sale%' AND partition_key = 20161129")                      
invoices_res = DataFrame(cur.fetchall())
invoices_res.columns = cur.keys()

cur.execute("SELECT invoice_ref_2 AS PPS_Id ,cast(total_amount  AS char(10)) AS Amount FROM core_invoices  WHERE  client_ref_id like 'payment_gc_sale%' AND partition_key = 20161129")                      
accrual_res = DataFrame(cur.fetchall())
accrual_res.columns = cur.keys()

final_res = invoices_res.merge(accrual_res, on='PPS_Id')

db.close()
```

When I execute the code I get,

> "PandasError: DataFrame constructor not properly called!"

Please assist.

Comment: what does `cur.fetchall` return? List of tuples or a tuple of tuples?

Comment: tuple of tuples:
Something like this: {(1, 50), (2, 60)}

Comment: that would be it then... the DataFrame constructor likes to take lists instead of tuples or sets for some reason. try: `DataFrame(list(cur.fetchall()))`